# psycopg2 how to call database when table name is starting with numbers

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to read tables from the postgres database but the name of table is in number so I am keep getting syntax error.
Any ways to solve this prob?

```
import psycopg2

conn=psycopg2.connect(host='host', dbname='database', user='postgres', password='postgres', port='5432')
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select* from database.public."123456";")
rows=cur.fetchall()
print(rows)

syntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from psycopg2 import sql    

query = sql.SQL("SELECT * FROM {table}").format(table=sql.Identifier('123456'))
cursor.execute(query)
```

using integers as name not good idea , see [formatting](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#module-usage) for sql in psycopg. your query is not proper string that's why you are getting syntax error.